# Javascript function not displaying correct result

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, dynamic-visualforce

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Price_Study__c" extensions="dynamicpicklist" sidebar="false" >
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryA, 'js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js')}" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryA, 'js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js')}" />
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryA, 'css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css')}" />
<apex:form id="form1">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Dynamic Picklist" subtitle="Reusable code"/>
<apex:pageblock id="saveblock">
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Dynamic picklist" columns="1" id="pbsectn">
      <apex:pageblocksectionItem id="pbs1">
          <apex:outputlabel value="City" for="values" />
          <apex:selectList value="{!city}" size="1" id="values" >
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" onsubmit="callControllerMethod(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)" reRender="newvalue"  />
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!citynames}" id="citynames"/>
          </apex:selectList>

      </apex:pageblocksectionItem>      
       <apex:inputField value="{!Price_Study__c.P3_Comments__c}" id="P1comment" style="width:200px;position:relative;height:15px;"/>                                  
          <apex:outputpanel id="newvalue">     
             <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!city == '--Other--'}">
             <div style="position:relative;left:75px;">             
                  <apex:outputlabel value="New value" for="newval" />
                  <apex:inputText value="{!newpicklistvalue}" id="newval"/>

                  <apex:commandbutton action="{!saverec}" value="Add!" />
                  <apex:commandbutton action="{!save}" value="save"/>
             </div>
             </apex:outputpanel>
          </apex:outputpanel>   
          <apex:commandbutton action="{!save}" value="save"/>          
  </apex:pageblocksection>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
<script>
function callControllerMethod(text) {
if(text!='--Other--'){
document.getElementById('{!$Component.form1.Saveblock.pbsectn.P1comment}').value=text;
}
if(text=='--Other--'){

}
}
</script>
</apex:page>
```

I tried with this command:

```
document.getElementById('{!$Component.form1.Saveblock.pbsectn.P1comment}').value=document.getElementById('{!$Component.form1.Saveblock.pbsectn.newvalue.newval}').value;
```

[image: If I select others in picklist it should take that value and equate to p1 comments box]

I have one pick list.When I select the value (Except option "--Others--")It will copy that value to p1 comments box using javascript which is working good.

When I select picklist value as "--Others--".It will open me new input box to add a new value. I want to copy that value to p1 comments box which is not working.

Which I click on add it should vale to p1 comment's box.

(OR)Whenever I enter a new value in the text box it should copy value to p1 comments box.

I Explained clearly about my issue.Let me know if you need more details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding another input field in your UI, you can use JavaScript [prompt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) function to collect the user input and add it in the p1 comment's box.

A recursive function can be used to force the user to provide input when other is selected. Check this [jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/nf5aLg17/) for a working demo.

Source code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Prompt</h2>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var otherval;
var txt;
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getOtherVal()+"";
}
  function getOtherVal(){
    otherval = prompt("Please enter other Value:", "");
    if (otherval == null || otherval == "") {
      getOtherVal();
    } else {
      txt = otherval;
      console.log(otherval);
    }   
    console.log(txt);
    return txt;
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi I am adding that value to my dynamic picklist